Github Actions deploy.yml file for CI4 project, asking for password and getting failed
name: Deploy to Server

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Setup SSH
        run: |
          mkdir -p ~/.ssh
          echo "${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
          chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
          ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts

      - name: Sync files to server
        run: |
          rsync -avz --delete-after \
          -e "ssh -i ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }} -p 222 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" \
          ./ root@192.168.1.1:/var/www/crm

When pushing the code to master branch the action getting started but failed on this error
Run rsync -avz --delete-after \
  rsync -avz --delete-after \
  -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p 222" \
  ./ root@192.168.1.1:/var/www/crm
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
Warning: Permanently added '[192.168.1.1]:222' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
root@192.168.1.1: Permission denied (publickey,password).
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(231) [sender=3.2.7]
Error: Process completed with exit code 12.

I added public key on Github with name SSH_PRIVATE_KEY and I have id_rsa, id_rsa.pub and authorised_keys file on this location ~/.ssh/ on the server.
I dont know what I am doing wrong, I have the SSH key passwordless.

I believe there is a typo and I corrected it here:
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -p 222 ….

I also suspect a typo here
I added public key on Github with name SSH_PRIVATE_KEY

Did you mean to say “private key”?
Also did you place the public key into
/root/.ssh/authorised_keys

on the target server 192.168.1.1?
Is this IP address correct? It looks surprising, considering that you are running on a GitHub hosted runner.
